# How to test programatically chosen external URL with Cypress for Bootstrap4 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, cypress

I am getting to grips with Cypress. Loving it so far, however, I have got stuck with the following.

I want to test that when a button is clicked, the user is directed to the correct external site. This works fine (at the moment) using the following code:

```
$("#my-button").click(function() {
  var external_url = 'https://www.somesite.com/';
  if($("#my-checkbox").prop("checked")) {
    external_url += 'foo';
  } else {
    external_url += 'bar';
  }
  window.location.href = external_url;

  return false;
});
```

Starting small within a Cypress spec:

```
it('Should direct to external site depending on checkbox state', () => {
  cy.get('#my-button').click()
})
```

Receives Cypress Error:
Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8888" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

This is fair enough, and I understand why I get the error. I don't want to disable Chrome Web Security to get around it.

Can someone show me how I should test this use case?

I think I should be trapping the location change with `cy.stub()` and/or `cy.on()` but so far I have not had success:

```
it('Should direct to external site depending on checkbox state', () => {
  cy.stub(Cypress.$("#my-button"), "click", () => {
    console.log('stub')
  })

  cy.on("window.location.href", win => {
    console.log('on')
  })

  cy.get('#my-button').click()
})
```

The button click still results in the error being thrown as the script still attempts to set the location to an external site.

Comment: Was there a particular reason for not wanting to disable the Web Security? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#External-Navigation Cypress recommends checking the href value as an alternative.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71277156/17865804) might help.