# Cypress throws "cross origin error happened on page load" even if host didn't changed

Tags: iframe, cypress, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I'm running Cypress tests on `https://localhost:3000`, which is my `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` also. Navigating to `/` redirects to `/en` internally, which works fine. But the test that I'm writing is about a form which builds a new URL, like `https://localhost:3000/foobar?param=value`. This works finde, I can even see the page that I'm redirecting to. But Cypress complains about this:

```
Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

  > Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:

  > https://localhost:3000

A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new URL which does not match the origin policy above.

A new URL does not match the origin policy if the 'protocol', 'port' (if specified), and/or 'host' (unless of the same superdomain) are different.

Cypress does not allow you to navigate to a different origin URL within a single test.

You may need to restructure some of your test code to avoid this problem.

Alternatively you can also disable Chrome Web Security in Chromium-based browsers which will turn off this restriction by setting { chromeWebSecurity: false } in cypress.json.
```

I do not want to disable `chromeWebSecurity` (which works), since I'm running this test on Firefox also. The only thing I can imagine is the way I do the redirect: `window.location.href = "/foobar?param=value"`.

The error message is about changing `protocol`, `port` or `host`, but I'm doing none of them, and my SSL certificate is a valid one.

Could this be a bug or did I overlooked something?

Comment: What happens if you go directly to `https://localhost:3000/en` to avoid that initial redirect?

Comment: What version of cypress are you using?

Comment: Take a look at Cypress browser URL when the test runs, Cypress changes `https://localhost:3000` from your `baseUrl` to `http://localhost:3000` (shows "Not secure" and https is struck out). So when later you navigate `https://localhost:3000/foobar?param=value` the protocol has actually changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error indicates that you might be performing requests to a different [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). An origin is the combination of protocol (`http`, `https`), domain (`myapp.com`, `localhost`), and port (`80`, `443`, `3000`).

So, all these are different origins:

- `http://localhost`
- `https://localhost`
- `http://localhost:3000`

Even if they are all in `localhost`, they use different protocols or ports, so, they are **different** "origins". Two objects have the same origin only when the protocol, domain and port all match.

In Cypress, this is a common issue for many others when performing redirections, for instance, as in your case (see the discussion [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4220)). As per the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-a-cross-origin-error-happened-on-page-load):

> **Cypress detected a cross-origin error happened on page load**
>
> This error means that your application navigated to a superdomain that Cypress was not bound to. Initially when you `cy.visit()`, Cypress changes the browser's URL to match the url passed to `cy.visit()`. This enables Cypress to communicate with your application to bypass all same-origin security policies among other things.
> When your application navigates to a superdomain outside of the current origin-policy, Cypress is unable to communicate with it, and thus fails.
>
> **If you find yourself stuck and can't work around these issues** you can
> set `chromeWebSecurity` to `false` in your configuration file
> (`cypress.json` by default) when running in Chrome family browsers (**this
> setting will not work in other browsers**). Before doing so, you should
> really understand and read about the reasoning [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security).
>
> `{"chromeWebSecurity": false}`

Also, as described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Same-superdomain-per-test):

> If you attempt to visit two different superdomains, Cypress will
> error. Visiting subdomains works fine. You can visit different
> superdomains in *different* tests, but not in the *same* test.

Thus, although you are visting a subdomain, you might want to consider the following, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Same-superdomain-per-test), which is used for visiting different superdomains:

```
it('navigates', () => {
  cy.visit('https://localhost:3000')
})

it('navigates to new origin', () => {
  cy.visit('https://localhost:3000/foobar?param=value')
})
```

Additionally, in the same documentation:

> Although Cypress tries to enforce this limitation, it is possible for
> your application to bypass Cypress's ability to detect this.
>
> **Examples of test cases that will error due to superdomain limitations**
>
> 1. `.click()` an `<a>` with an `href` to a different superdomain.
> 2. `.submit()` a `<form>` that causes your web server to redirect to you a different superdomain.
> 3. Issue a JavaScript redirect in your application, such as `window.location.href = '...'`, to a different superdomain.
>
> In each of these situations, Cypress will lose the ability to automate your application and will immediately error.

See [common workarounds](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Common-Workarounds).

Comment: I think he asks why is there a cors error when it appears there is actually no superdomain change.

Comment: So you're saying it is a bug? Very confusing to me, this answer.

Answer (score 6):

See [Does Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) differentiate between HTTP AND HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542686/16997707) for a definition of superdomain

> Yes, HTTP and HTTPS origins are different.
>
> An origin is a combination of hostname, port, and scheme.
>
> ```
>  http://foo.example.com:8080/
>  ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
>   ||           ||        ||
> scheme      hostname    port
> ```

So if I run this test I get the CORS error

```js
it('throws a CORS error', () => {

  const domain1 = 'https://localhost:3003'
  const domain2 = 'http://localhost:3003'
  
  cy.intercept(domain1, '<html></html>').as('lh')  // stubbing because no server running

  cy.visit(domain1)

  cy.wait('@lh')

  cy.window().then(win => {
    win.location.href = domain2    // Cypress detected a cross origin error happened...
  })
})
```

[image]

In your test, there could be a couple of reasons

- normally `localhost` uses `http://` not `https://`. If you try it the browser give you ***This site can’t provide a secure connection***. May be Cypress is correcting the scheme when it sees hostname `localhost`.
- Your main page is using scheme `http://` but your redirect is navigating to `https://`.